# search a list of objects by attributes and return rest of attributes associated with that object

Tags: c#, list, search, object

I have a list of objects(People) these people have certain attributes with them, e/g name, age, DOB etc. How would I do about searching for a certain person by their name and then returning the rest of the data belonging to that person.

I would just like some hints on what to look up been really struggling for a few days with it now and for the life cant think of how to do it.

Comment: Post the code you have and someone will be able to guide you better. For example, this can be done easily with Linq but before providing a solution, you should post some code.

Comment: Please paste some code in and specify which version of .net (if any) you are using. E.g. can you use LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx) is the most readable imho:

```
var alfreds = allPersons.Where(p => p.Name == "Alfred");

foreach(Person p in alfreds)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Next {0} Age:{1} DOB:{2}", p.Name, p.Age, p.DOB);
}
```

If you are looking for exactly one person or you want to take the first "Alfred"(e.g.):

```
Person p = allPersons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Alfred");
if(p != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Next {0} Age:{1} DOB:{2}", p.Name, p.Age, p.DOB);
}
```